# How to integrate Payfort in flutter or is there a different payment processor available in flutter?

Tags: flutter

What are the popular payment processors in flutter?, because I opened a Payfort account, but have not found documentation for flutter. I only found native ios and native android. What payment processor can I use in flutter?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use GooglePay by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_pay).

ApplePay by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_apple_pay).

Stripe by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment).

or Braintree by using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree).

And the PayFort package is still unavailable --maybe just yet.
Maybe you want to read the PayFort API's documentation [here](https://docs.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html).

hope it will help.

Comment: @ hisam thanks , i found another payment called myfatoorah available document and sdk for flutter